# Sequential server: behavior on accept(2) call

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I have a server with a TCP-socket in a non-concurrent single process implementation.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int sock_ds, acc_sock_ds, opt, client_addr_l;
    unsigned short port;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;


    /*Parsing command line: port-number retrieving*/
    /*...*/

    printf("Port number retrieved (%d), server is starting ...\n", port);

    /*TCP Socket creation*/
    sock_ds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if(sock_ds == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket creation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Server address binding*/
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    //use setsockopt(2) with OS_REUSEADR ???
    if(bind(sock_ds, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Address binding error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Server with passive socket*/
    if(listen(sock_ds, SOMAXCONN) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Listen call error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Server is ready. Waiting for connections.\n");

        /*Busy-waiting server*/
while(1){

    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
    acc_sock_ds = accept(sock_ds, &client_addr, &client_addr_l);
    /*Connect error management*/
    if(acc_sock_ds == -1){
         errsv = errno;
         if(errsv == 12 || errsv == 23 ){
            /*Fatal errors ENOMEM, ENFILE*/
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error on accept\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
         else if(errsv == 103 || errsv == 4 || errsv == 71 || errsv == 92 
                 || errsv == 112 || errsv == 113 || errsv == 95 || errsv == 101)
             /*ECONNABORTED, EINTR, EPROTO, ENOPROTOOPT, 
              * EHOSTDOWN, EHOSTUNREACH, EOPNOTSUPP, ENETUNREACH*/
             continue;
         else if(errsv == 100 || errsv == 64){
             /* ENETDOWN - ENONET */
             /*start timeout...*/
             continue;
         }
    }
  }
}
```

In this test I expected that the server will continue to make the call `accept(2)` also on failure. I know there are some terminal error conditions such `EBADF`.  Should I provide for a different behavior (termination of the process) depending on the value of `errno`? For which values ​​the server must be stopped and for which may continue waiting?

Code edited. I never made ​​the error handling via errno. If there are errors or suggestions please notify them. I noticed that the two conditions `ENETDOWN` - `ENONET` are implied by the absence of network. Should I expect for these situations a timeout to prevent stalling?

Comment: Most people prefer a switch and symbolic names for the errornumbers.

Comment: Where i can find examples? As I said i never done this before and google failed me.

Comment: I'll rewrite your while loop for you. Wait a sec ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error codes documented for `accept(2)` on MacOS X (and which should be consistent for most any POSIX compliant system):

- `EBADF` - programmer error - can't happen if the original `socket` call succeeded
- `ECONNABORTED` - try again
- `EFAULT` - programmer error - can't happen unless `&client_addr` is invalid
- `EINTR` - call interrupted, try again
- `EINVAL` - "socket is unwilling to accept connections" - I'm not sure how that would happen.  It *might* be due to not calling `listen(2)` first (programmer error) although apparently on some OS it can also be caused by the `namelen` parameter being negative (also programmer error)
- `EMFILE` - programmer error - you ran out of per-process FDs but that shouldn't happen unless you forgot to close them
- `ENFILE` - the system ran out of FDs - this is probably fatal
- `ENOMEM` - the system ran out of memory - this is probably fatal
- `ENOTSOCK` - programmer error - can't happen unless you passed an FD that wasn't a socket
- `EOPNOTSUPP` - programmer error - can't happen unless you pass a socket that isn't `SOCK_STREAM`
- `EWOULDBLOCK` - programmer error - your socket was configured as non-blocking

In addition, it appears that Linux systems can also generate `ENETDOWN`, `EPROTO`, `ENOPROTOOPT`, `EHOSTDOWN`, `ENONET`, `EHOSTUNREACH`, `EOPNOTSUPP`, and `ENETUNREACH`.  These are network errors for which you should loop.

In summary, you should probably:

- exit the program for `ENFILE` or `ENOMEM`
- loop on `ECONNABORTED` and `EINTR`, and the list above from Linux
- `assert()` during your debugging  for anything else - these runtime errors should only happen due to logic errors in the code, and not because of network related events.

Comment: Linux has this to say "In addition, network errors for the new socket and as defined for the protocol may be returned.", thus I'd be vary to exit the program on other/unknown errors as to not open up for clients to DOS the server.

Comment: @nos interesting, although I think for TCP the `ECONNABORTED` is pretty much it, i.e. the three way handshake didn't complete.

Comment: It's more - another part of the linux manpage mentions "Linux accept() (and accept4()) passes already-pending network errors on the new socket as an error code from accept().  This behavior differs from other BSD socket implemen‐
       tations.  For reliable operation the application should detect the network errors defined for the protocol after accept() and treat them like EAGAIN  by  retrying.   In  the
       case of TCP/IP, these are ENETDOWN, EPROTO, ENOPROTOOPT, EHOSTDOWN, ENONET, EHOSTUNREACH, EOPNOTSUPP, and ENETUNREACH."

Comment: Should I do a loop either in these last cases as well?

Comment: @FabioCarello yes, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Stylistic:

- use the symbolic constants instead of putting them in comments
- when unexpected error at least report the error number
- handle the default/unexpected cases, too

BTW: most of the symbolic constants below  don't seem to exist.

---

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <strings.h>

 /* Busy-waiting server */
while(1){

    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
    acc_sock_ds = accept(sock_ds, &client_addr, &client_addr_l);
    /*Connect error management*/
    if(acc_sock_ds == -1){
        switch(errsv=errno) {
            /*Fatal errors ENOMEN, ENFILE, all others*/
        default :
        case ENOMEM :
        case ENFILE :
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error on accept %d(%s)\n"
                , errsv, strerror(errsv)
                );
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            /* normal NON-ERROR error conditions */
        case ECONNABORTED :
        case EINTR :
        case EPROTO :
        case ENOPROTOOPT :
        case EHOSTDOWN :
        case EHOSTUNREACH :
        case EOPNOTSUPP :
        case ENETUNREACH :
             continue;
        case ENETDOWN :
        case ENONET :
             /*start timeout...*/
             continue;
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just copied the (wrong) symbolic constants from the comments in the OQ. As I said: most of them appear to be non-existent.

Comment: There was an error in the comments. All other constants are resolved. Which ones are not solved by your compiler?

Comment: I only noticed that they were not highlighted. I cannot remember if I compiled, only edited it to show the idea of the improved readability of a switch construct.